# why does bf like button shows comment box for some and not others?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

... one of our clients provided a js script link from addThis.com  to have FB, twitter and G+ buttons displayed throughout their site as a share bar. What I've noticed is that for some people clicking the Like button displays the comment box and for some it does not. This cased some issues since we have to use yet another '4th' party jQuery plugin to have the sharebar remain statically positioned on the page, disappear from view under certain conditions, etc.

Thus I was asked to just hide the comment box permanently and I did. Found some nasty hack that AT LEAST FOR NOW seems to work well cross browser.

But I need to document what's going on. Any ideas? I watched one of our QA people hit like on the same page i did and they did not get the comment box, while I did. What drives that?

Client is using the iframe implementation of the like button if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's an option for you but have you tried to disable the comments option with css?

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget iframe.fb_ltr {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: ... yes, that's the 'hack' I'm making reference to :-)